# Help with possible errors on LM306 datasheet circuit diagram

Tags: datasheet, error

Not sure if this diagram has some errors like missing nodes at wire crossing. There is an obvious one at a T-intersection but also I circled in red a couple other locations where nodes might be missing. One is below R9 because no output comes off the collector of Q8. The other is between R13 and R14 because it's strange (to me) that they are separate with nothing connecting to them in between. The circuit still does not work, so if anyone sees any other problems please let me know. Thanks.[image: LM106/LM306 National Semiconductor datasheet]

Comment: Q7 and Q8 form a long-tailed pair, one will produce an inverted version of the other. They only need one of the outputs in this circuit.

Comment: Great, thanks. What about the other between R13 and R14?

Comment: It's all very interesting finding a potential error in a data sheet but, for this particular device does that potential error prevent you from using it within the specifications in the data sheet? After all, many op-amps/comparators don't have internal schematics and, for most folk, that's just fine. So, why should these errors bother you given that the circuit is largely irrelevant and the part is virtually dead in the water?

Comment: The other way around. It prevents me from simulating this comparator and trying to "match" the datasheet.

Comment: Your LM306 datasheet is completely different to the LM306 datasheet found in a Google search today.

Comment: Some later datasheets from TI and National have a different model. However, i would like to use this model for historical reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this other comparator, the LM111/LM311, which was designed shortly after the LM306 has the same or a very similar circuit layout. Based on that it seems that those two nodes are missing from the LM306 datasheet. BTW, the LM306 circuit does "work" with some device (BJT) model parameters but not others. Getting a good fit to the datasheets is next. [image]